# Show $\sup_{x > a}\frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a > 0$. I'm trying to show that

$$\sup_{x > a}\frac{\sin x}{x}  < 1$$

Of course, showing it is $\leq$ is not hard: one uses that $\sin x < x$ for $x > 0$. Looking at the graph, this is quite obvious, but I can't make it formal.

Comment: If you can show that it is $\le 1,$ then just show that the equality never holds. That is, show that $\sin x\ne x.$

Comment: @Allawonder How do I do that?

Comment: Since $\sin x-x\le 0,$ show that $\sin x-x$ is increasing for $x\ge 0,$ and that it vanishes at $x=0.$

Comment: @Allawonder Actually, this does not quite help. Because $\sin(x)/x < 1$ for all $x > a$ does not imply $\sup_{x > a} \sin(x)/x <1$.

Comment: Combined with the answer below it does help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, by contradiction, that the sup is $1$. That means there is a sequence $x_n$ with $x_n\ge a>0$ such that $\sin x_n/x_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. This sequence either contains a subsequence convergent to some finite $L>0$ or a subsequence diverging to infinity. The latter is impossible because if $x>2$, $\sin x/x<1/2$. In the former case, by continuity you would have $\sin L/L=1$ which is false.